# Web Store - Linking to specific categories without hard-coding IDs

Tags: database

Say I have an online catalog which contains (for our purposes) 2 tables:

### Category

id
name

### Product

id
category_id
name

If I wanted to link to a specific category -- say for instance, the most important category for any given section of the site -- without hard-coding IDs, what would be the best practice for this?  Would I use some type of "SLUG" column that is assigned upon category creation and can't be modified?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It can be accomplished several ways, as is the case with most things, but creating a column to contain a url-friendly version of the category name is one option.  I can't say it's the "best" solution though, because it depends on the situation.

What's the problem with giving an ID number in the URL though (e.g. /22-blah-blah-blah)?  I prefer doing it that way so I can change the title part without breaking people's bookmarks. Not sure how that goes for SEO, but it doesn't seem to have hurt me so far.

My CMS has a routing table that encompasses multiple entity types (products, pages, etc..) rather than relying on multiple tables for routing information.

Comment: Yeah, currently I have the slug column in the tables, which is what I'm linking to.  Just wondering how it would be handled if the admins should decide that the category deserves a new name.

Comment: If they must change the category name, I say let them and then alter the URL.  You *could* go so far as to implement a sort of "history" table to provide routing for old URLs (so you could redirect the old name to the new name.)